# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')

Tags: next.js

The issue I'm facing is that the program is executing until the point where the log statements are printed inside the callback of the bulkLoad operation. However, it's terminating early without sending a response. The POST function seems to return before the callback within bulkLoad is completed, leading to this unexpected behavior. I am getting 500 error from the server.

Could someone please guide me on how to structure my code correctly to ensure that the response is sent only after the bulkLoad operation and its callback are finished? Any insights, suggestions, or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

```
export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const data = await request.json();
    const excelData: ExcelDataProps[] = data.excelData;
    appValidationID = data.appValidationID;
    const connection: Connection = await connectToSQLServer();
    const bulkLoad = connection.newBulkLoad(TABLE_NAME, (error, rowCount) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        return NextResponse.json(
          { mssg: error.message },
          {
            status: 500,
            statusText: "Internal Server Error",
          }
        );
      }
      connection.close();
      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          mssg: `${rowCount} rows inserted...`,
        },
        {
          status: 200,
          statusText: "OK",
        }
      );
    });
    const columns = [
      { name: "TASK_ID", type: TYPES.Int, nullable: false },
      {
        name: "TESTCASE_NUM",
        type: TYPES.VarChar,
        length: 100,
        nullable: false,
      },
      {
        name: "ISSUE_TITLE",
        type: TYPES.VarChar,
        length: "max",
        nullable: false,
      },
      {
        name: "ISSUE_Recommendation",
        type: TYPES.VarChar,
        length: "max",
        nullable: true,
      },
      { name: "STATUS", type: TYPES.VarChar, length: 25, nullable: false },
      { name: "GUID", type: TYPES.VarChar, length: 100, nullable: false },
    ];

    columns.forEach((col) => {
      bulkLoad?.addColumn(col.name, col.type, {
        nullable: col.nullable,
        length: col.length,
      });
    });

    const uniqueId = uuid4();
    const dataToBeAdded = excelData.map((row) => {
      return {
        TASK_ID: appValidationID,
        TESTCASE_NUM: row.TestCase_NUM,
        ISSUE_TITLE: row.Issue_Title,
        ISSUE_Recommendation: row.Issue_Recommendation,
        STATUS: row.Status,
        GUID: uniqueId,
      };
    });

    if (bulkLoad) connection.execBulkLoad(bulkLoad, dataToBeAdded);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    NextResponse.json(
      {
        mssg: "Unable to make connection to sql...",
      },
      {
        status: 500,
        statusText: "Internal Server Error",
      }
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: pls check it is working for you

const bulkLoadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const bulkLoad = connection.newBulkLoad(TABLE_NAME, (error, rowCount) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error.message);
          reject(error);
        } else {
          connection.close();
          resolve(rowCount);
        }
      });

Comment: yeah, I have wrapped some other necessary code inside the promise and it's working. Thanks